# is there a way to export a model to a csv in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

In Mysql workbench, I have created a model with eight tables, and about 50 columns.

is there a way to export the model (not data) into a csv?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the following query:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/model.csv'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
```

You can find some more information about the COLUMNS table [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html).

Comment: duh.  I could have thought of that.  in my head, i was thinking from mwb to csv.  it's a friday.  lol.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised that this is accepted as answer, as it is plain wrong. This solution dumps existing objects in a server to a csv file, not a WB model (which contains objects that may or may not be in a real db already). Additionally, a model consists of more than just tables + columns.